Using ArduinoModbus library to read a holding register with value -1
client.read() function in ArduinoModbus library returns -1 on failure: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/arduinomodbus/client.read/. How can it be used to read a holding register with value -1?
One option would be to monitor client.lastError(), but there seem to be no way to reset the lastError, so it would work only up to the first failure.

My guess is that for a register with signed type value, e.g. int16_t, one has to extract the lower 16-bits from uint32_t value returned by client.read().

wouldn't modus transmit only bytes? ... those do not have a sign

@jsotola Modbus registers can have negative values, therefore sign matters.

my guess is that the data would be read as an unsigned integer ... the data could be 2 bytes and the value returned by the library 4 bytes ... the top two bytes used to make the number negative

@jsotola Yes, I think so. I was adding a comment to my post to this effect, while you've sent yours.

here is an example how this works ... the first line would be an error message ...  the second 32 bit value is not negative, but the 16 bit data is negative ... https://wokwi.com/projects/403163467946550273

There are two errors that return -1, for the Arduino Modbus library, an error from the client for -1 means "I/O error", for the Modbus protocol, the exception 1 means "illegal function code". calling client.lastError() would return a string interpretation of what the error code means. Please provide your code and what you are trying to reset/set via the modbus? are you using TCP or RTU protocol?

How do you send int16_t as the modbus function code? why there is a need for using int16_t for modbus function code instead of uint16_t or two bytes of uint8_t? Are you aware that Modbus is using Big Endian during transmission while whatever you stored in the Arduino is in Small Endian?

@hcheung I posted my code as an answer.

According to the Wikipedia description of the Modbus data
model, “input registers” and “holding registers” hold 16-bit
unsigned numbers, in the range 0–65,535 (0x0000–0xffff). This is
consistent with the ArduinoModbus client.write() prototype,
which takes an unsigned int parameter.
The client.read() function, on the other hand, returns a
long. This is typically a 32-bit number that can hold all the possible
legit values, and also −1 to signify an error condition.
If, contrary to the Modbus data model, your Modbus device transmits
signed values, you should check its datasheet to see how negative values
are encoded. It will most likely use the two's complement
representation, which is the one used internally in the Arduino. If this
is the case, what the device holds as −1 will be read by the library as
65,535. You can easily get the correct number by converting to
int16_t:
long result = client.read();  // use `long` to not loose information
if (result == -1) {
    handle_the_error();
    return;
}
int16_t value = result;  // convert to the device's type
if (value == -1) {
    handle_a_legit_minus_one();
}


Here is my code to solve this problem and additionally separate error code from read value. Modbus data model mentioned in another answer is insufficient for modern hardware, which forced many manufacturers to go beyond it, in order to use int32_t, uint32_t and float registers.
template<typename T>
bool holdingRegisterWrite16(ModbusTCPClient &modbus, int addr, T arg) {
  return modbus.holdingRegisterWrite(addr, arg);
}


template<typename T>
bool holdingRegisterRead16(ModbusTCPClient &modbus, int addr, T &arg) {
  static_assert(sizeof(T) == 2, "arg has to be a 16-bit type");

  auto res = modbus.holdingRegisterRead(addr);

  if (res == -1)
    return false;

  memcpy(&arg, &res, 2);
  return true;
}


template<typename T>
bool holdingRegisterWrite32(ModbusTCPClient &modbus, int addr, T arg) {
  uint16_t word0, word1;

  memcpy(&word0, &arg, 2);
  memcpy(&word1, (char*)&arg+2, 2);

  return 
    modbus.beginTransmission(HOLDING_REGISTERS, addr, 2)  && 
    modbus.write(word0)  &&  modbus.write(word1)  &&  modbus.endTransmission();
}


template<typename T>
bool holdingRegisterRead32(ModbusTCPClient &modbus, int addr, T &arg) {
  static_assert(sizeof(T) == 4, "arg has to be a 32-bit type");

  if (modbus.requestFrom(HOLDING_REGISTERS, addr, 2) != 2) 
    return false;

  auto res0 = modbus.read();
  auto res1 = modbus.read();

  if (res0 == -1  ||  res1 == -1)
    return false;

  memcpy(&arg, &res0, 2);
  memcpy((char*)&arg+2, &res1, 2);
  return true;
}

